# How to make a plugin interface for a C program

Tags: c, plugins

I'm looking for a way to create a plugin interface for a C program. In the interest of a short and concise example, let's say I have the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int complexFunction(int a, int b) { return a+b; }
int main() {
    int a = 3;
    int b = 6;
    printf("The result of C(a, b) is %d.\n", complexFunction(a, b));
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of using the defined `complexFunction` however, I would like to allow the user to code their own and then plug-in their implementation.

I have never worked with plugin implementations myself, but so far I have been able to come up with the following possibilities for a plugin interface:

1. Create a 'mini scripting language' which my program can parse and create a procedure pipeline for, then pass the variables into that pipeline. This would involve a lot of 'generic' functions for each possible action in the scripting language.
2. Use a pre-existing scripting language for the same purpose (however this may not be possible as I would need some very specialised scriptable functions).
3. Allow the user to write and compile a C file containing the definition of `complexFunction(int, int)`, and dynamically load that at run-time. This is the least secure option but for development purposes it would be ideal as (only) I would author my own plugins and I could dynamically add functionality to my program.

My question is twofold:

- What are the common ways of handling plug-in capabilities in Applications?
- How can I accomplish **(3)** / is **(3)** even possible in C? After `fopen`-ing a file, can I somehow use it as code in the current program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A scripting language (usually a pre-existing one like lua or something) is the most common way.  3 is possible-  you could look in a predefined folder for dynamic libraries (.so or .dll files) and look for functions with specific names.  Its doable, but there's huge security issues with it (you have no security really).

Answer (score 1):

3)

If the user can compile your function into a .dll, you can use the following steps:
a) use [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to load the dll
b) use [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the address of the function
c) execute the function

Example:

```
typedef int (__cdecl *PCF)(int, int);
HMODULE hDll = LoadLibrary("x:\\Dllpath\\MyPlugIn.dll");
if (hDll != NULL)
{   PCF pfnComplexFunction = GetProcAddress(hDll, "complexFunction");
    if (pfnComplexFunction != NULL)
    {   int a = 3;
        int b = 6;
        printf("The result of C(a, b) is %d.\n", pfnComplexFunction(a, b));
    }
    FreeLibrary(hDll);
}
```

The function in the dll would need to be declared like

```
__declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl complexFunction(int a, int b)
{   return a + b;
}
```

Comment: This answer is Windows-specific.